# Connecting two phones using socket

Tags: android, sockets

Is it possible to connect two phones using socket programming?
I tried following code but it didn't work

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    serverStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.server_status);

    SERVERIP = getLocalIpAddress();//Public function to get ip address to it is //working fine 

    Thread fst = new Thread(new ServerThread());
    fst.start();
}

public class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        try {
            if (SERVERIP != null) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        serverStatus.setText("Listening on IP: " + SERVERIP);
                    }
                });
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8087);
                   } else {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        serverStatus.setText("Couldn't detect internet connection.");
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    serverStatus.setText("Error");
                }
            });
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? What happened?

Comment: yes it is however it is unlikely you will ever be able to connect two phones via direct sockets that are connected via phone providers networks due to NAT etc...

Comment: The Code i have written is working fine.
It was showing error because i didn't give permission for internet

    android.permission.INTERNET

it is working now

Comment: @NileshTupe Dear bro, i have same problem as  you had, can you send me the code where two Android devices will connect with each other through WIFI and will able to send file to each other, please please please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible but I think the first thing you should do is read up on [Java Socket programming](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/) as there are a few problems with your code that make me think you haven't quite got a grasp of it yet. The main problems are:

1. Your `ServerSocket` never accepts a connection and is therefore never actually 'listening'.
2. Even if it was listening, if this code is running on both phones they would both only be listening and not actively seeking a connection with each-other.

You will need to implement a client on one phone and a server on the other like @Deepak has shown.

Also, you may want to check out `AsyncTask` in [this article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) for updating views from a non-UI thread (instead of a handler).

Finally, make sure your app includes the `android.permission.INTERNET` permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: Thanx Gary... Code i have written is working fine.
It was showing error because i didn't give permission for internet

    android.permission.INTERNET 

it is working now

Answer (score 2):

As per socket programming two client socket cannot connect each other. similarly two server socket cannot connect eachother. The code you have written tells that you have written server socket. u need a client socket which will connect to server socket. to create client socket u need ip and port of server socket. Please have a look on the code below. Donot forget to vote if you find the response is useful for you. The below example is in core java. u can implemnet the both in andriod also.

```
Server
-------
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


class TCPServer
{
   public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
      {
         String clientSentence;
         String capitalizedSentence;
         ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);

         while(true)
         {
            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            BufferedReader inFromClient =
               new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
            System.out.println("Received: " + clientSentence);
            capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase() + '\n';
            outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);
         }
      }
}



Client
--------------
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;


class TCPClient
{
 public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
 {
  String sentence;
  String modifiedSentence;
  BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6789);
  DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
  BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
  sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
  outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');
  modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
  System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence);
  clientSocket.close();
 }
}
```

Thanks
Deepak